# Help with css targeting

Tags: css, css-selectors

IT should be something easy, but still I cant target it. What I have:

```
#navigation li a:hover .menu-description {
  color: #000000;
}
```

What I want to do whenever user goes on #navigation li a class .menu-description should change color to black. How to target this? Maybe, any links on how to target such types of css?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're going about it completely incorrectly. Please post some markup so we can walk you through what you want to happen.

Comment: @zzzzBov maybe he's not... It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4kJ8z/ I've done this a bunch of times and it is useful.

Comment: http://vienaskomentaras.us.lt/ - I want the grey italic text to go black on hover. Tried your variant, but it didnt work.

Comment: @Donny: your HTML is all wrong. Your italic text isn't even nested within the anchor tag you are applying your hover to. You can't do what you want to do with CSS only with your current HTML.

Comment: That link is dead. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with the kind of HTML you're working with, so we can help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to say without seeing your HTML. Based on what you have, the HTML to match would have to be something like this:

```
<[tag] id="navigation">
    <ul/ol>
        <li>
           <a>
               <[tag] class="menu-description">
               </[tag]>
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </[tag]>
```

Comment: and a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4kJ8z/ (if you don't mind me posting it here... don't feel like making a whole answer for this)

Comment: DA>>http://vienaskomentaras.us.lt/ - I want the grey italic text to go black on hover. Tried your variant, but it didnt work.

Comment: Does your HTML match what I have above? If not, that's your problem. Or the problem is something else--but we'd need to see a lot more CSS and HTML to be of help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your link. No, your HTML does not match what I have. Your italics text is a span that's outside of the anchor tag. There's no way to do what you want to do with CSS based on your HTML. You could use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigation li a.menu-description:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

hover is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigation li a.menu-description:hover  {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: http://vienaskomentaras.us.lt/ - I want the grey italic text to go black on hover. Tried your variant, but it didnt work.